# SDL 3D platform consistency

Tags: c++, opengl, multiplatform, sdl-2

The simple direct media layer (SDL) provides a layer that allows the same code to compile into a consistent multiplatform application.  However for 3D graphics SDL uses OpenGL.  OpenGL has a known history for being inconsistent across platforms, even on just the PC platforms (Windows, Linux and Mac) so my question is does this still apply when using OpenGL with SDL?  Or has SDL provided a solution for this inconsistency?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by "inconsistent across platforms". The functions do pretty much the same things. And no, SDL doesn't do anything to make those functions work differently than they ordinarily would on each platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this still apply when using OpenGL with SDL?

Yes.

> Or has SDL provided a solution for this inconsistency?

No.  Closest they have is [the 2D accelerated rendering](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender) API which wraps OpenGL/OpenGL ES/DirectX as necessary.